# Powershell - Internet Explorer - Get document for a newly opened tab

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, powershell, automation

I am trying to figure out how to login to web-pages in Internet Explorer 9 using PowerShell version 2 on Windows 7 x64. When I run these lines one by one in PowerShell, I get exactly what I want - The page opens and I am able to login.

```
$internet_explorer = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$internet_explorer.visible = $true
$internet_explorer.navigate2("https://abcd.efgh.com/ijkl/Login.jsp")
$this_document = $internet_explorer.document
$username_field = $this_document.getElementByID("usernameField")
$password_field = $this_document.getElementByID("passwordField")
$login_button = $this_document.getElementByID("SubmitButton")
$username_field.value = "username"
$password_field.value = "password"
$login_button.click()
```

But when I try to open another tab and try to login to the new webpage by executing the below lines one-by-one,

```
$internet_explorer.navigate2("https://mnop.qrst.com/uvwx/Login.jsp", 0x0800)
$this_document = $internet_explorer.document
$username_field = $this_document.getElementByID("usernameField")
$password_field = $this_document.getElementByID("passwordField")
$login_button = $this_document.getElementByID("SubmitButton")
$username_field.value = "username"
$password_field.value = "password"
$login_button.click()
```

I get the following errors :

```
Property 'value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:1 char:17
+ $username_field. <<<< value = "username"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (value:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Property 'value' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:1 char:17
+ $password_field. <<<< value = "password"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (value:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:20
+ $login_button.click <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

So when I open a new tab, how can I get `Document` of that newly opened tab? Please help me solve this

EDIT : Alternative methods will do. Please feel free to suggest any other way to login to multiple web pages automatically (like what was attempted above) if they exist

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for the Navigate method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa752133.aspx), it would appear that the new tab is not available for automation:

> When navOpenInNewWindow or navOpenInNewTab is specified, the caller does not receive a pointer to the **IWebBrowser2** interface for the new window, so there is no immediate way to manipulate it.

Comment: So is there any other way to fulfil the original purpose of logging into multiple web-pages (like using multiple windows, using another method, using another browser, using another tool, etc.) ?